# Passing dynamic parameters to exp:channel:entries

Tags: members, solspace, solspace-user

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work.

I have a custom member field called local_tunnel. I can retrieve that value no problem with either Solspace User which I have installed or the native EE tags.

However if I try and pass in either of those as a parameter for channel entries tag I get no results, not even the no_results tag is evaluating. I've tried hard coding a value and that works.

```
 <div class="bolder">
                    {exp:user:stats}{member_tunnel}{/exp:user:stats}
                    {exp:member:custom_profile_data}{member_tunnel}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
                        {exp:stash:parse process="end"}
                        {exp:channel:entries 
                                channel="tunnels" 
                                entry_id="{exp:member:custom_profile_data}{member_tunnel}{/exp:member:custom_profile_data}"
                                limit="1"
                                disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
                            }
                            {title}
                            {if no_results}
                            <p>No Results</p>
                            {/if}
                        {/exp:channel:entries}
                        {/exp:stash:parse}
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use a full tag pair as the parameter of another tag, because that tag pair won't be parsed until *after* the tag it is being used as a parameter for is parsed.

Instead, try this:

```
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
    {exp:member:custom_profile_data}
        {exp:channel:entries 
            channel="tunnels" 
             entry_id="{member_tunnel}"
             limit="1"
             disable="categories|category_fields|pagination"
        }
            {title}
            {if no_results}
                <p>No Results</p>
            {/if}
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    {/exp:member:custom_profile_data}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you Derek, the parse order gets me every time.